# Why are there two different .subckt for an IC model I've downloaded?

Tags: ltspice, pspice

I've downloaded a .lib file containing the .subckt model of L6562A. It contains two different .subckt as follows:

[image]

One of them has an "av" suffix. Is it an average model or something? How can I use them? Which one should be applied in the simulation of an actual circuit?

The comparison between these two .subckts are presented as follows:

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the models? Are there no explanations for why there are two of them? They look very similar, so maybe one of them is a reworked/updated version. Have you tried them as per the datasheet? To avoid waiting for a full cycle of a 50 or 60 Hz input, you can use a frequency ten times higher and reduce by one tenth the capacitors in the control loop (see LTspice's test jig for LT1249 for a reference).

Comment: @Kamran Did you miss the part where I suggested the datasheet?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, the available schematic in the datasheet itself contains a bunch of elements that their spice models are not available. what do you recommend?

Comment: @Kamran You're interested in testing, so instead of some custom diode bridge just use *a* diode bridge, instead of a specific MOS use *some* MOS, or even a VCSW(+antiparallel D), etc. The trafo is explained right below: "*1.5 mm gap for* **0.7 mH** *primary inductance*". No need for fuse, or NTC. Suppose your manager asked you to use the datasheet to test some model, what would you do: ask the manager the questions that you asked me? I'm asking because you seem to have a model that you want to use, but you can't even make use of its datasheet? Just curious: how did you plan on using it?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, sorry, I am a novice. and this is my first real project. how can I apply a gap in an inductor in LTspice?

Comment: Just use two coupled inductors. Moderators might not agree with prolonging the discussion which is very much off-topic now. So if you have questions different than this one, it's better to make new ones.